# How to implement a "bank transaction" like table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Take the following example:

```
Operation Signal Value    Balance
1         +      100.00   100.00
2         +      50.00    150.00
3         +      10.00    160.00
```

Now I have two concurrent transactions that take the last operation, add the value and then save (insert). The values are never updated.

**Transaction 1**

Takes the last operation (3) and locks it "for update" and inserts

```
Operation Signal Value    Balance
1         +      100.00   100.00
2         +      50.00    150.00
3         +      10.00    160.00
4         +      10.00    170.00
```

**Transaction 2**

Takes the last operation and locks it "for update". Since the first transaction has a "for update" lock, it waits to get the latest. In this example transaction 2 began before transaction 1 ended.

The actual row returned from postgresql is #3 (after the fist lock is released). So it ends up like this:

```
Operation Signal Value    Balance
1         +      100.00   100.00
2         +      50.00    150.00
3         +      10.00    160.00
4         +      10.00    170.00
5         +      10.00    170.00
```

So the balance ends up 170.00. The desired is to be 180.00.

This is in the READ_COMMITTED transaction mode.

With SERIALIZABLE mode **Transaction 2** throws an error about concurrency.

I have tried the following:

- Selected the latest row with "for update";
- Selected a row with `this_is_the_last = true` `"for update"`, changed it to `false` and then inserted a new one with `this_is_the_last = true`. PostgreSQL ends up returning a row with `this_is_the_last = false` even if it's not (on transaction 2 after transaction 1 relases the `for update` lock).

Is there a way to make a row level lock and make transaction 2 wait for transaction 1 in a way that transaction 2 will not select the same "latest" as transaction 1?

Comment: You need to use SERIALIZABLE here; you'll get concurrency errors, which means you have to rollback and retry.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of “lost update” need never happen in PostgreSQL, even if you use `READ COMMITTED` isolation.

Define `operation` as the primary key constraint on the table.

Each of your transactions will execute:

```
INSERT INTO transaction (operation, signal, value, balance)
SELECT operation + 1,
       '+',
       10,
       balance + 10
FROM transaction
ORDER BY operation DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Then if there is a concurrent transaction, one of the two will receive a primary key violation, since `operation` is unique. That transaction simply retries the operation until it succeeds.